# Always execute some code after overloaded constructors

Tags: java, object, constructor, instance

I want some code (for example, "setBackground(Color.BLACK);") to be executed within every overloaded constructor of this subclass (or I can also mean "some code" must be executed after instance of this subclass is created). But this "some code" can be used/called only inside our subclass and only once. And every overloaded constructor of this subclass must always call appropriate overloaded constructor of the superclass.

```
public class JLProgressBar extends JProgressBar{

    public JLProgressBar(){

        super();

    }

    public JLProgressBar(int orient){

        super(orient);

    }

    public JLProgressBar(int min, int max){

        super(min,max);

    }

    public JLProgressBar(int orient, int min, int max){

        super(orient,min,max);

    }

    public JLProgressBar(BoundedRangeModel newModel){

        super(newModel);

    }

}
```

Comment: Would an [initialiser block](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-26-the-initializer-block-in-java/) cover your needs?

Comment: @BeUndead, yes, thank you very much!
But bad thing is, that it executes before constructor.

Comment: They run after the call to `super` in a constructor.  So in the contexts you've posted it should be effectively _after_ all of these.  Is there other code not posted here running  in these constructors?

Comment: @BeUndead, rechecked it - you're right! Everything works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to an answer for future reference.

Java's [Initialiser blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) should resolve the issue.  These are injected into each constructor directly after the call to `super`, which (in the examples you've provided) should cover happening at the appropriate times.  Additionally, these will only run once, and are *guaranteed* to run for every instance which gets created (regardless of if someone subclasses your class, etc.).

For example

```
public class YourJProgressBar extends JProgressBar {

    public YourJProgressBar() {
        super();
    }

    {
        // Whatever code you want in here, will run immediately after the call
        // to 'super' in any given constructor.  Note, in cases where the call
        // to 'super' is implicit, it will run after that implicit call
        // instead of just never running.
        this.setValue(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `static` block will be called each time the class is loaded.

```
public class JLProgressBar extends JProgressBar{

    static {
        System.out.println("hhh");
    }

    public JLProgressBar(){
        super();
    }

    public JLProgressBar(int orient){
        super(orient);
    }

    public JLProgressBar(int min, int max){
        super(min,max);
    }

    public JLProgressBar(int orient, int min, int max){
        super(orient,min,max);
    }

    public JLProgressBar(BoundedRangeModel newModel){
        super(newModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it to be executed after instance of the class is created (and it must be not in static context).

Comment: @marick0073 if you want to call it inside constructor, create a function and call it from each overloaded constructor

Comment: As I mentioned, it can be called/used only once (so I can't call it from each overloaded constructor).

Comment: only one constructor will be *called*, so the method will only be called once (per instance)

Comment: @user85421 yes, I understand this. But function used in few places (in every overloaded constructor). And I want it to be used only in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an instance initializer. This initializer can handle or your required "some code" for all constructor variants.

```
public class JLProgressBar extends JProgressBar{

    public JLProgressBar(){
        super();
    }

    public JLProgressBar(int orient){
        super(orient);
    }

    public JLProgressBar(int min, int max){
        super(min,max);
    }

    public JLProgressBar(int orient, int min, int max){
        super(orient,min,max);
    }

    public JLProgressBar(BoundedRangeModel newModel){
        super(newModel);
    }

    // instance initializer (called for every constructor
    {
        // "some code"
    }
}
```

Note: this instance initializer will run **after** the super constructor but **before** any other code in the constructor. So

```
public class Bar
{
    protected int a;

    public Bar()
    {
        a = 2;
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    {
        a = 1;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

public class Foo extends Bar
{
    public Foo()
    {
        super();
        a = 4;
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    {
        a = 3;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Foo();
}
```

... will print

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: init() used more than once (but must only once).
Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your comment. init() should only be used once in each constructor.

Comment: @marick only one constructor will be *called*, so the method will only be called once (per instance) ((despite IMO an instance initializer is more appropriate))

Comment: @ultimate you used init() few times in your code (you used it in every overloaded constructor). I want it to be used only once.

Comment: @user85421 yeah, I understand this. I mean that method must be used only once in the code (but he used it inside every overloaded constructor). Sure, instance initializer is more appropriate.

Comment: @user85421: thanks for that hint. Didn't know instance initializers - was only aware of static initializers. Update my answer respectively